# Update with SUM()

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table structure similar to the ones below

```
Table1

BatchID     Quantity     ProductID
1           10           1

1           10           1

1           20           2
```

I need to group by Product ID and get the max quantity and then sum that up and update table2. So the result in table2 would be

```
Table2

BatchID    Total
1          30
```

The update query i came up with was

```
UPDATE T2
SET
Table1.Total = Sum(sub.quantity)
FROM Table2 T2
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        MAX(T1.Quantity) quantity,
    FROM Table1 T1
    GROUP BY T1.ProductID,Ti.Quantity) AS sub ON sub.BatchID= T1.BatchID
WHERE T1.BatchID = 1
```

When i run this query it throws this error
"An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement."

Please help me fix this error.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/90477

Comment: Do you have an entry in Table2 for each batch or does that need to be generated as part of this?  Also can you explain the logic behind using a MAX() and why you don't consider productID?

Comment: You probably have to store the sum into another variable first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest the subquery one more time...I think mssql can handle that.   :

```
UPDATE T2
SET
Table1.Total = sub.quantity
FROM Table2 T2
INNER JOIN 
select sum(a.quantity) as quantity
from
(SELECT 
    MAX(T1.Quantity) quantity,
FROM Table1 T1
GROUP BY T1.ProductID,Ti.Quantity)a) AS sub ON sub.BatchID= T1.BatchID
WHERE T1.BatchID = 1
```

Comment: Thanks!! It was the nesting that i was missing. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Anytime, tis what we enjoy doing at SO ;)   don't forget to accept the answer if you're good with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
update table2 
    set total = coalesce((select sum(max_quantity)
                          from (
                              select max(Quantity) as max_quantity 
                              from table1 
                              where table1.batchid = table2.batchid 
                              group by productid
                         ) as tmp), total);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your issues:

```
UPDATE  a
SET     Total = b.Quantity
FROM    Table2 a
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT x.BatchID ,
                            SUM(y.Quantity) AS Quantity
                     FROM   Table2 x
                            INNER JOIN ( SELECT z.BatchID ,
                                                z.ProductID ,
                                                MAX(z.Quantity) Quantity
                                         FROM   Table1 z
                                         WHERE  z.BatchID = 1
                                         GROUP BY z.BatchID ,
                                                z.ProductID
                                       ) y ON y.BatchID = x.BatchID
                     GROUP BY y.BatchID
                   ) b ON a.BatchID = b.BatchID
```